# IndexError: list index out of range to a question of the beecrowd

Tags: python-3.x

I am solving a question from (https://www.beecrowd.com.br/). When I submit the code appears the following error: "Runtime Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/judge/judge-b0deebbf632c4423b5e2cda08b4aeba3.d/Main.py", line 24, in 
if (isPrime(vet[i])):
IndexError: list index out of range"

Follows the code:

```
import math

def isPrime (N):
    if N == 1:
        return False
    if N == 2:
        return True
    root = int(math.sqrt(N)) + 1
    for i in range(2,root):
        if N % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

fact = []
fact.append(1)
for i in range(1, 100):
    fact.append(fact[i-1] * i)


N = int(input())
vet = [int(item) for item in input().split()]

for i in range(0,N):
    if (isPrime(vet[i])):
        print("{0}! = {1}".format(vet[i],fact[vet[i]]))
```

When I execute this code in my computer work normally(the version installed is the 3.5.2
). I finded various solutions, but none solve. How I can solve this?

Comment: What is `vet`? Seems like it's empty

Comment: It is received by usuary using input from inside from following code: "vet = [int(item) for item in input().split()]"

Comment: I think that I find the error. If I digit the N and after give a "enter"(twice) by the keyboard appears this error. How i can solve?

Comment: Still seems like it's empty. So what is the input? How can I reproduce this if we don't know what the inputs are.

Comment: If you're pressing enter twice, the second input is empty. Thus your error.

Comment: I have that to look a form of solve this!